# Is there any alternative of parent child data structure in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have 50+ fields in my solr index. Few fields are parent fields of other fields.
Earlier we had decided to keep everything flat and duplicated the parent fields
with child fields.
Now we have run into a problem. If we need to change a parent field we have to reindex every document containing that field.

Is there any way I can manage these parent and child fields separately?
I know there is parent child structure in solr but I need the same par performance as flat structure.
So is there any alternative or tuning available to achieve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Block join query parser. It will also contain a flat structure. You just need to maintain your hierarchy logically in order to fetch your records

https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers

Comment: I have never used it, is it's performance same as using flat structure ? As I think it stores data In nested structure.

Comment: Try creating records using nested structure and then query from solr dashboard you will found out that solr is providing records in flat structure